# Let users create custom blade layouts / store in database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

**Problem**: I need to let my web-app users *create their own blade layout templates*. So the most convenient solution is to store the blade templates into the database. However, I see no method to `extend` a child `view` from a layout code `NOT SPECIFIED` in a `blade file`.
Furthermore the next concern is security. I can't rely on users to insert `safe code`. Giving access to insert `php` code or directly `blade` code is disastrous for the system.
So how to?

1. Save the layout template in database
2. Make sure no part of the code gets executed on the server side.

As a side note, I can let users mention pre-specified tokens in the code, that shall be replaced by the results from the system.

Comment: Voted off topic based on opinion "request". Input into your approach should be sent to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Don't do that. Close because it's off-topic here, not because it might be on-topic elsewhere. There's a very good reason Code Review is not a migration target.

Comment: If you found a solution to your original problem, you are allowed to self-answer your question.  That would probably be the path to take here, as this is not a "do you like my code" forum.

Comment: Checkout @elliot-rodriguez  .. I changed it to question answer form.. But this needs to stay here. I've seen people asking this question. And thanks for codereview link...

Comment: @Mast Hmm. Ok. Oh this is not the question I attempted to close now anyway. Now its just WAY TO BROAD

Comment: @riggsfolly Is this question & it's answer worth a downvote?

Comment: @patrick-q Is this question & it's answer worth a downvote?

Comment: @mast Is this question & it's answer worth a downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote this question

Comment: Don't ask me. Did you read the [help/on-topic]?

Comment: @mast I did.. and I see it conforms to the rules. Don't you think?

Comment: I did vote to close as Off-Topic: 
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @riggsfolly I re-wrote the whole question. It isn't off-topic anymore. Please re-read.

Comment: Question has been posted (in better form) on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/134992/52915).

Comment: No this question is still OFF-TOPIC, for a start there are 2 questions

Comment: Okay what shall I do with this one? Delete it? or what? It has directly lead to ban of asking questions.@riggsfolly

Comment: A suggestion please @riggsfolly

Comment: I have no idea if deleting this will clean up your reputation.

Comment: No it won't.. But is it really this useless to be here? I am not that experienced around here. So should I keep it or delete it? @riggsfolly

Comment: **I have no idea**, ask me a simpler question!

Comment: I have no f***ing clue why this is down-voted...

Comment: Although this is an old post, but I had a similar use case which I posted my own solution on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489775/save-blade-templates-to-database-rather-than-file/50075222#50075222) in StackOverflow. In case it helps anyone who comes across this post. Like I did in moshing up different ideas I read on Stack to build the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Solution 1:** Let users fill the database column (after filtering the given code for any possible php codes) and save it into a 'master' file, from which the final view is being extended. User may use given codes for content replacement

```
//master.blade.php
<html>
<head>
<%token%>
</head>
<body>
<%content%>
...
<%scripts%>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code, the **<% content %>**

should be replaced by

> @yield('content')

before the actual view is processed.

```
//final.blade.php
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
...
@endsection
```

So the controller, saves the database column content into ***master.blade.php*** and then calls the ***view('final')*** function as necessary.

```
//In Controller
//Save the contents of database column in master.blade.php
return view('final',$data);
```

But this is **NOT a GOOD solution**. File write operation for every request, cache problems, security issues (such as service side execution script injection) etc.
An alternate to this is having a master for each user, created only when the user makes changes in the template column. Thus benefiting from lesser file write operations, but file overload on the server because a file for every user in the file-system.

---

**Solution 2:** Save the user's layout code into database column (no filtering necessary).

```
//In controller
$content = View::make('final',compact('data'));
$token = "<meta name='_token' content='" . csrf_token() ."'";
$scripts = View::make('final_scripts',compact('data'));

$view = str_replace_first("<%content%>", $content, $templateInDatabase);
$view = str_replace_first("<%token%>", $token, $view);
$view = str_replace_first("<%scripts%>", $scripts, $view);

return $view;
```

The user shall be made to include the three **<%X%>** tags in the template code.
Benefits are no server side code execution, hence added security. Cache problems minimize as the *final* & *final_scripts* blade templates can be cached. But the string replacements add extra effort.